# How to ensure that content within a column vector do not touch?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, matrices, vector, displaystyle

I have some variables defined in a column vector written in mathmode in the usual way

```
$\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{i} \\ \dfrac{1}{j} \end{bmatrix}$
```

However, the result shows that they are almost touching each other like this:
[image]

Is there a way to somehow expand the vector brackets so that there is some space between the i and the 1? Like a vertical `\thinspace`

Comment: Try ``\\[2ex]`` (experiment with different figures)

Comment: (use `{}` not `"` markup for code sections) you can add space after `\\[2cm]`  but why are you using `\dfrac` here not `\frac` that is a major cause of the problem, forcing the fractions to be over-large for the context.

Comment: in this case you should also be able to add `\mathstrut` to the denominator of the top fraction to give it some depth.  but, as pointed out elsewhere, it's really bad form to use display-style fractions in in-line math, and doubly bad to use them in an in-line matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\` has an optional parameter. You can write (precise values according to you taste):

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{i} \\[18pt] % here - PS
 \dfrac{1}{j} \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

I have changed `$...$` to `\[...\]` because so high matrix in text mode is not a good idea.

Comment: more latex secreets

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{i} \\ \dfrac{1}{j} \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```